# Run JavaFX app from the command line without GUI

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX in which the user can select files to be processed. Now I want to automate it so that you can run the application from the command line and pass those files as a parameter. I tried to do this:

`java -jar CTester.jar -cl file.txt`

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    if (Arrays.asList(args).contains("-cl"))
    {
        foo();
    }
    else
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The main is executed and the argument is correct, but this still creates the GUI.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html):

> The entry point for JavaFX applications is the Application class. The
>   JavaFX runtime does the following, in order, whenever an application
>   is launched:
>
> - Constructs an instance of the specified Application class
> - Calls the init() method
> - Calls the start(javafx.stage.Stage) method
> - Waits for the application to finish, which happens when either of the following
>     occur:
>
>   - the application calls Platform.exit()
>   - the last window has been closed and the implicitExit attribute on Platform is true
> - Calls the stop() method

So if I cannot use the `main` method, how can I create this "alterantive" flow? I thought about creating a normal java application as a wrapper but that seems a little bit overkill for such a simple task. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply exit the application after calling your `foo()` method:

```
Platform.exit();
```

Here is a quick sample application to demonstrate:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CLSample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (Arrays.asList(args).contains("-cl")) {
            commandLine();
            Platform.exit();
        } else {
            launch(args);
        }

    }

    public static void commandLine() {
        System.out.println("Running only command line version...");
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        root.getChildren().add(new Label("GUI Loaded!"));

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("CLSample Sample");
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

If you pass `-cl`, then only the `commandLine()` method gets called.

Comment: @cuoka Note the reason `Platform.exit()` is required here is because the JavaFX runtime is started when the `Application` subclass contains the `main` method—even if you don't call `Application#launch`. Moving the `main` method to a separate class would avoid this problem (including unnecessarily starting the JavaFX runtime).